# Template PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, contacts

Hey guys Ive just bought a template and the customer support is refusing to help me unless I pay them on top of the fee of the template I already bought... fuming.

So im left with good ol' Stack Overflow friends that I know will help me out on this one.

So the problem is with the contact form only...

They havent provided the PHP file and I want to know whats wrong with my one....

This is the code for the contact form - HTML

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f837-p60-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
        <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
        <form action="php/contacto.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <p>Your Name (required)
                <br /> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="name" /></span> </p>
            <p>Your Email (required)
                <br /> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="email" /></span> </p>
            <p>Subject
                <br /> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" id="subject" /></span> </p>
            <p>Your Message
                <br /> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="6" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" id="message"></textarea></span> </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />
            </p>
            <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my php file inside php folder...

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['name']) && strtoupper($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captcha_id'] )
{
    $to = 'info@mywebsite.com'; // Replace with your email  
    $subject = 'Message from website'; // Replace with your $subject
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
               'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
               'Subject: ' . $_POST['subject'] . "\n" .
               'Message: ' . $_POST['message'];

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Whats going on? are you getting errors ?, nothing happen ?

Comment: Nothing happens just a blank page :( @NicolasRacine

Comment: That page has no output so you *should* see a blank page. Do you get an email from that script?

Comment: No nothing John, no message at all... @JohnConde

Comment: do you see something wrong with this: `<input type="text" name="your-name" ` ?

Comment: mmm not sure what... @CodeGodie